# post text box value in ajax data

Tags: ajax

trying to insert value in my ajax post data from text box but not working if set default value of text box then its shows the value but i need something to work on user input value.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <?php 
        function test($data){
            return $data;
        }

        if (isset($_POST['callFunc1'])) {
            echo test($_POST['callFunc1']);

        }
    ?>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <div onclick="myfun()" >Clck Me</div>
    </form>


    <script>
        var names = $("#name").val();

        function myfun(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { "callFunc1": names},
            success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
        });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: It looks right to me. Have you tried the pure JavaScript solution:  document.getElementById('name').value

Comment: yes also try but no success :/

Comment: I think you should put the         var names = $("#name").val();
into the myfun() function to be like this     
        function myfun(){
 var names = $("#name").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: { "callFunc1": names},
            success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
        });

Comment: yes exactly thankyou :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should put the `var names = $("#name").val();` into the `myfun()` function to be like this:

```
function myfun(){

    var names = $("#name").val();

    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { "callFunc1": names},
      success: function(response) { console.log(response); }
    });
}
```